# Looking to Change Intellisense Autocomplete shortcut for Javascript in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

So when I am working with C# in Visual Studio 2012/2013 I always type CTRL + ENTER to Autocomplete Intellisense selections. But when working with Javascript/CSS you press ENTER only. I find myself constantly pressing CTRL + ENTER when working with Javascript/CSS in Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 and I am wondering if there is an option somewhere to change the Intellisense Autocomplete shortcut from ENTER to CTRL + ENTER for Javascript.

Comment: Difficult to unlearn this and switch to using Tab instead.  It can be done.

Comment: Sure, I was just noticing Enter is an option too. Enter in C# does the same as CTRL + ENTER so I can switch to ENTER. Tab seems a bit far away ;).